# Hide values of sliderInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to hide the values of the sliderInput in Shiny.

Currently, I have the following:

[image: sliderInput]

And I would like to get rid of the zero and the twelve, so nothing is shown.

I have set `ticks = FALSE` and played around with `pre` and `post`, but I cannot achieve the desired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edited to show help from @jenesaisquoi in comments**

You can use CSS to select the specific value boxes you want hidden, and set their visibility to "hidden".  I'm terrible at CSS, so this is very ugly, but technically it answers your question:

```
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-min, .irs-max {
            visibility: hidden !important;
    }'))),
    sliderInput("test", "slider", 0,12, value = c(0,12))))
server = shinyServer(function(input, output){

})

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

I'm mostly posting this in the hopes that someone will correct me.

Comment: Also if you have many sliders and you might want to display apply those changes to specific one(s) , use their ids in the `css` e.g. `.js-irs-2` for slider number 2

Answer (score 3):

To hide the current slider value as well, include `.irs-single`.

```
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-min, .irs-max, .irs-single {
            visibility: hidden !important;
    }'))),
    sliderInput("test", "slider", 0,12, value = c(0,12))))
server = shinyServer(function(input, output){

})

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```